# Netbeans 3 on Windows 7

Tags: netbeans, windows-7

Has anyone managed to make Netbeans 3 work on Windows 7?  I realise this is against everything that is holy, but I either try and get it working, buy new hardware, or upgrade the whole project to a later IDE...

I had to manually set my JAVA_HOME and place a folder path on the command line when running the installer, but after that I am getting the following error in the install log:

```
Found matching JVM at c:\Java\jdk1.5.0_06
Matching JVM home is c:\Java\jdk1.5.0_06
Matching JVM file is C:\Users\spalmer\AppData\Local\Temp\LRE72A4.tmp
Executing launch script command: "c:\Java\jdk1.5.0_06/bin\java.exe" -cp "";"C:\Users\spalmer\AppData\Local\Temp\LRE72A5.tmp\setup.jar";"" -Dtemp.dir="C:\Users\spalmer\AppData\Local\Temp" -Dis.jvm.home="c:\Java\jdk1.5.0_06" -Dis.jvm.temp="0" -Dis.media.home="C:\Users\spalmer\AppData\Local\Temp\LRE72A5.tmp\setup.jar" -Dis.launcher.file="C:\development\surveycollector\trunk\docs\Everything you need to set up a survey collector\netbeans-3_6-windows.exe" -Dis.jvm.file="C:\Users\spalmer\AppData\Local\Temp\LRE72A4.tmp" -Dis.external.home="C:\development\surveycollector\trunk\docs\Everything you need to set up a survey collector"   -Xms20m -Xmx60m  run  in working directory C:\development\surveycollector\trunk\docs\Everything you need to set up a survey collector
Output from the launch script execution
StdOut:

ErrOut:
An error occurred during wizard bean change notification:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Dimension.java:91)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(BasicProgressBarUI.java:757)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1615)
    at com.installshield.wizard.awt.ColumnLayout.layoutContainer(ColumnLayout.java:174)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1401)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1390)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1473)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1448)
    at com.installshield.wizard.awt.AWTWizardUI.setCurrent(AWTWizardUI.java:1827)
    at com.installshield.wizard.awt.AWTWizardUI.runnableBeanStarted(AWTWizardUI.java:1873)
    at com.installshield.wizard.StandardWizardListener.execute(StandardWizardListener.java:127)
    at com.installshield.wizard.StandardWizardListener.currentBeanChanged(StandardWizardListener.java:106)
    at com.installshield.wizard.Wizard$RunThread.run(Wizard.java:1545)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Dimension.java:91)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(BasicProgressBarUI.java:757)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1615)
    at com.installshield.wizard.awt.ColumnLayout.layoutContainer(ColumnLayout.java:174)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1401)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1390)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1473)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1448)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:379)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:113)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Dimension.java:91)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(BasicProgressBarUI.java:757)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1615)
    at com.installshield.wizard.awt.ColumnLayout.layoutContainer(ColumnLayout.java:174)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1401)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1390)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1473)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1448)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:379)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:113)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Dimension.<init>(Dimension.java:91)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicProgressBarUI.getPreferredSize(BasicProgressBarUI.java:757)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1615)
    at com.installshield.wizard.awt.ColumnLayout.layoutContainer(ColumnLayout.java:174)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1401)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1390)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1473)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1480)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1448)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:379)
    at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(SystemEventQueueUtilities.java:113)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:461)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

Comment: What is preventing you from moving to NetBeans 6.9?

Comment: I'm just figuring that out.  I think the big change is the way projects are organised, but I suspect this may be the best solution.  It is a biggish bite for us though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest importing the project to a newer version of the IDE. You'll make the code more accessible for future needs. Otherwise you're just perpetuating an obvious problem.

If that's not possible (sometimes it's not our call) here's another VM option you can check out: http://www.virtualbox.org/

Answer (score 1):

I just found a simpler fix to our problem:

`C:\Java>SET JAVA_HOME='C:\j2sdk1.4.2_17'`

`C:\Java>netbeans-3_6-windows`

As you see, that's all I had to do and Netbeans installed perfectly, using Java 1.4 as runtime.

Just in case you need it still.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) (Windows XP Mode or Win 7). Installing Netbeans 3 on it might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Java 5 is too new for NB3. Try Java 1.4.2 or maybe even 1.3.something.

Comment: actually 1.5 is the recommended version for NetBeans 3, so I don't think it's that.

Comment: Ok, you must be on NB 3.6, which is the first that cited Java 1.5 compatibility. Earlier than that and it was 1.4, or 1.3 for NB 3.1. At any rate, you are getting an NPE in Dimension which (assuming the app worked properly on another platform) suggests a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar NPE in a different szenario with an old JExpress installer. I found a [workaround](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6337517).

The workaround is to change desktop theme to some default theme like Win XP or Classic. Then this problem does not happen.